# How do I watch Blueprint 3 iTunes LP on an Apple TV?

Tags: appletv

I updated the Apple TV OS with iTunes LP support. I had purchased the iTunes LP for Blueprint 3 a month ago, and it works fine on my Mac. But, I can't figure out how to watch it on the Apple TV. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue on the [Apple Support forums](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2215478&tstart=0&start=15).

Apple had to release an AppleTV compatible update, and it is now available.